# Logout redirect to wrong page

Tags: php, logout

When I click on the logout why it redirect me to wrong page. I'm using locahost to develop my page but when I click logout it will redirect me to xampp page, it suppose redirect me to admin page.

```
     case 'logout':
        log_activity('user logout', $curr_path);
        system_user_stopsession();
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$web_path);
        break;
```

Comment: $web_path may be empty

Comment: The reason could be a lot of things; an empty `$web_path`, hitting the wrong switch case, the destination redirecting again. You give too little information for us to work with. More code and more debugging info would help.

Comment: I solved the problem which I create another php file to redirect it to  the function.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `/` between the host and path:

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/".$web_path);
```

Comment: Try this before, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing `"http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/".$web_path`? Does that URL actually exist?

Comment: Ya the URL is existed, I using this method in login as well.